# Launch projectile like a missile - box2d and libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d, projectile

I want to launch a projectile(an object) like a missle, with constant velocity(x,y) but I want the projectile to fly according to the user touch.

How can I achieve something like this?

P.S I tried to do something like this but it's not what I need. It flies to a constant point regardless of the user touch. Also it is affected by gravity:

```
package com.david.helpers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.david.objects.Acorn;

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor{

    private Body ground;
    private Vector2 target;
    private Vector3 temp;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Array<Acorn> acorns;
    private static final float Pixels_To_Meters = 32.0f;
    public boolean isTouchDown = false;
    public InputHandler(Body ground,  Array<Acorn> acorns, OrthographicCamera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.ground = ground;
        this.acorns = acorns;
        target = new Vector2();
        temp = new Vector3();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.unproject(temp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        target.x = temp.x;
        target.y = temp.y;
        isTouchDown = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        acorns.peek().getBody().applyLinearImpulse(20-target.x/Pixels_To_Meters, 20-target.y/Pixels_To_Meters*0.1f, target.x, target.y, true);
        isTouchDown = false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.unproject(temp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
        target.x = temp.x;
        target.y = temp.y;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    public Vector2 getTarget() {
        return this.target;
    }
}
```

The body moves to a constant point regardless of the user touch.

Comment: I edited my post and added my InputProccessor class. Could you please help me?

Comment: No, I can't help you, I don't know that programming language, but your question is much better than it originally was.  It would be better still if you offered some diagnosis of the problem(s) you have, simply writing *it's not what I need* leaves it to the reader to try to figure out what's wrong.  Since you must already have done that it's a little perverse not to share the information with would-be helpers here on SO.

Comment: I edited my post. Now it should provide all the necessary information to help me.

Comment: I think the parameters you are giving to ApplyLinearImpulse are wrong. The first two parameters should be the direction of the movement you want (eg. target position minus current position) and the next two parameters should be where to apply the impulse (usually at the body position).